# C++ array contents changing in between function calls

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, overflow

**Example code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

class compArray {
public:
    unsigned int* myArr; //The array

    compArray() {
        unsigned int temp[4];
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            temp[i] = 0;
        }
        myArr = temp;
        print_arr(myArr);
    }

    void set() {
        print_arr(myArr);
    }

    static void print_arr(unsigned int* arr) {
        printf("Printing the array============\n");
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            printf("%u\n",arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
};

main() {
    compArray test;
    test.set();
}
```

**The output:**

> Printing the array============
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>
> Printing the array============
>   134513919
>   3221174380
>   0
>   0

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, but why is this happening?

Comment: Must be a full moon today. This is the 1,965,233rd question today for which the correct answer is: Don't use pointers, use `vector<>`.

Comment: Not to mention that this code is not legitimate C++....

Comment: @Rob2: No, the correct answer is don't point to variables that go out of scope. Using a `vector` will not fix the bug.

Comment: @Loadmaster - perhaps you are right. But I claim that if he had not used a pointer at all (that is, declared `vector<int>myArr` instead of `int*myArr`), then he would have never created this bug.

Comment: @Vlad, how is it not legitimate C++? I see nothing wrong with it, other than main wasnt declared to have a return type

Comment: @Dan F: How about return value types? ISO C++ forbids declarations with no return types. Some old C compilers assumed `int` by default, but that's not the case with C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your constructor, you have these two lines:

```
unsigned int temp[4];
...
myArr = temp;
```

You set your member variable pointer `myArr` equal to the address of your local variable `temp`. But, `temp` goes out of scope *and is destroyed* as soon as you return from the constructor.

After that, `myArr` refers to storage that is no longer allocated, and exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Because this isn't an array:

```
   unsigned int* myArr; //The array
```

...it's a pointer.  A pointer and an array are different things entirely.  Arrays can be decomposed in to pointers in some cases, but they still aren't the same thing.

This is the array:

```
      unsigned int temp[4];
```

...and it's falling off the stack at the end of the function.

When you do this:

```
myArr = temp;
```

...you aren't copying the contents of the array, you're just copying the address of the first element of the array.  When the function in which `temp` is allocated exits, the array itself falls off the stack, and `myArr` becomes a wild pointer, pointing to uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int temp[4];
for (unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    temp[i] = 0;
}
myArr = temp; // OOPS!
```

You initialized myArr to a value that was on the stack.  When the constructor finished executing, the C++ Compiler was free to reuse that space, and, it did.